# Как убрать редирект в урл с заглавных букв на маленькие в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, yoast

Как сделать так, что бы Вордпресс не редиректил урл с заглавными буквами на маленькие?

Пробовал через .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${tolower:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Так же пробовал через  function.php

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Еще пробовал реализовать так, но тоже не помогло...

```
function preserve_utm_case() {
    if (isset($_GET['gclid'])) {
        $_GET['gclid'] = strtoupper($_GET['gclid']);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'preserve_utm_case');
```

Стоит плагин Yoast seo. Возможно он мешает...
Подскажите плиз.